# Function, that takes string and number as parameter for creating filename

Tags: php, c++

I have to create different data files in a loop.
There are three file-types i want to generate like

typeA%00d.txt,

typeB%00d.txt and

typeC%00d.txt

For this i want to implement a function that takes a sequential number and a string as parameters.

Something similar to this:

```
void make_file(paarvec data, int count){ 

 int size = data.size();
 char filename[160];
 sprintf(filename, "name%03d.txt", count);

 ofstream out_data(filename);
 for(int n=0; n<size; ++n){
    out_data << data[n].first << "\t" << data[n].second << endl;
    }
 out_data.close();
}
```

But is there a way that i also can change the "name" of the file with an argument. So that i can write:

```
std::string timestring = "timedata";
std::string timestring = "pathdata";
...

for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
  ...
  make_file(time_data, timestring ,count);
  make_file(frac_data, fracstring ,count);
  make_file(path_data, pathstring ,count);
}
```

Comment: What law prohibits you from simply adding another parameter to `make_file()`?

Comment: maybe i did something wrong, but it did not work :(

Comment: "Hello, Chuck's auto repair? My car doesn't work, can you fix it?" -- do you expect to get a meaningful answer to that?

Comment: Actually i get a meaningful answer of smart and friendly Slava below... Thanks a lot to Slava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your function to:

```
void make_file(paarvec data, const std::string &name, int count){ 

  int size = data.size();
  char filename[160];
  snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s%03d.txt", name.c_str(), count);
  ...
```

Note I changed `sprintf` to `snprintf` - it is a good habit to prevent bad surprises in your code like buffer overflow.